# XslTransform Transform Doesn't Add URL

Tags: .net, xslt, transform

The following code is what I am using to transform an XML Document into an HTML document:

```
XslTransform vXslTransform = new XslTransform();
XmlReader vReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(this.Xslt));
vXslTransform.Load(vReader,null as XmlResolver, null as System.Security.Policy.Evidence);

StringWriter vStringWriter = new StringWriter();
vXslTransform.Transform(this.XmlDocument, null, vStringWriter, null);
```

This code has been working for years. Then I come along, and all I want to do is add a URL to the mix. You can see the new URL in the XML below (CoreReturnLabel element):

```
<CoreReturnEmail>
<CoreReturnLabel>https://www.example.com/SomePage.pdf?token=eaf5383bddb9382f5&amp;createdby=f01ddedb0aedd87fe44b9b9b741</CoreReturnLabel>
<CoreReturn>
    <CoreReturnID>12345</CoreReturnID>
    <HashedCoreReturnID>sdjhgfuidhcbjhsdgifljsdjgfuio</HashedCoreReturnID>
    <VendorShipItem>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <VendorShipment>
            <ActualShipDate>5/31/2016</ActualShipDate>
        </VendorShipment>
        <VendorOrderItem>
            <OrderItem>
                <CoreCharge>40.00</CoreCharge>
                <PartsearchSKU>
                    <Item>
                        <Name>Some name</Name>
                        <Description>That thing</Description>
                        <DisplayNumber>734-3647-4748</DisplayNumber>
                        <Brand>
                            <PreferredName>Brand</PreferredName>
                        </Brand>
                        <AdditionalShippingType>
                            <Description>No Additional Shipping Charges</Description>
                        </AdditionalShippingType>
                    </Item>
                </PartsearchSKU>
                <OrderItemState>
                    <Name>Sourced</Name>
                </OrderItemState>
                <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                <UnitSellingPrice>179.00</UnitSellingPrice>
                <LineDiscountTotal>0.00</LineDiscountTotal>
                <LineTotal>895.00</LineTotal>
                <UnitAddShippingFee>0.00</UnitAddShippingFee>
                <UnitAddShippingFeeLineTotal>0.00</UnitAddShippingFeeLineTotal>
                <IsOversizedShipping>False</IsOversizedShipping>
            </OrderItem>
            <VendorOrder>
                <OrderNumber>12345678</OrderNumber>
                <Order>
                    <ReturnsPortalUrl></ReturnsPortalUrl>
                    <ShipToFirstName>CHICAGO</ShipToFirstName>
                    <ShipToLastName>CHICAGO</ShipToLastName>
                    <ShipToAddressLine1>1600 Parkway PKWY</ShipToAddressLine1>
                    <ShipToAddressLine2></ShipToAddressLine2>
                    <ShipToCompany>CHICAGO</ShipToCompany>
                    <ShipToCity>The one</ShipToCity>
                    <ShipToPostalCode>12345</ShipToPostalCode>
                    <ShipToProvince>
                        <Code>AL</Code>
                    </ShipToProvince>
                    <ShipToCountry>
                        <Name>United States</Name>
                    </ShipToCountry>
                    <BillToFirstName>Yep</BillToFirstName>
                    <BillToLastName>Me</BillToLastName>
                    <BillToAddressLine1>That place</BillToAddressLine1>
                    <BillToAddressLine2></BillToAddressLine2>
                    <BillToCompany>CHICAGO</BillToCompany>
                    <BillToCity></BillToCity>
                    <BillToPostalCode>12345</BillToPostalCode>
                    <BillToProvince>
                        <Code>AL</Code>
                    </BillToProvince>
                    <BillToCountry>
                        <Name>United States</Name>
                    </BillToCountry>
                    <OrderChannel>
                        <Name>OC1</Name>
                        <DisplayName>OC1</DisplayName>
                        <Code></Code>
                        <AuthorizationType>
                            <Name></Name>
                            <Code></Code>
                            <Description></Description>
                        </AuthorizationType>
                        <PrimaryURL></PrimaryURL>
                        <WebSiteOrderChannelCode></WebSiteOrderChannelCode>
                        <CustomerServicePhone></CustomerServicePhone>
                        <PhoneDescription></PhoneDescription>
                        <EmailDomain></EmailDomain>
                        <ClientCode></ClientCode>
                        <PCI></PCI>
                        <ClientProgram>
                            <BrandedName></BrandedName>
                            <DaysAllowedForCoreReturn></DaysAllowedForCoreReturn>
                        </ClientProgram>
                    </OrderChannel>
                </Order>
                <Vendor>
                    <Name></Name>
                </Vendor>
            </VendorOrder>
        </VendorOrderItem>
    </VendorShipItem>
</CoreReturn>
```

The XSLT is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="isFred">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/OrderChannel/WebSiteOrderChannelCode,'GSSC')">       yes      </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Your Core Has Been Received</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            </head>
            <body style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;">
                <table width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="string($isFred)">
                                    <img src="http://content.gif" border="0" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="string-length(CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/OrderChannel/PrimaryURL) &gt; 0">
                                            <a href="http://{CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/OrderChannel/PrimaryURL}">
                                                <img src="http://content.gif" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <img src="http://content.gif" border="0" />
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:21pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;">Core Return:</span>
                            <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;"> Order #</span>
                            <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #f43400;">
                                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/OrderNumber" />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14pt;">Hello        <xsl:if test="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order"><xsl:text></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/ShipToFirstName" /></xsl:if>,</span>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14pt;">         This email communication is to provide the information necessary to make your core return fast and easy.         <br /><br />                To complete your core return, please email <a href="mailto:othershared@company.com">otherShared@company.com</a>.              </span>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <table style="background-color:#dfedf3;" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">Core For:</td>
                                    <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/OrderChannel/ClientProgram/BrandedName" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">Part Ship Date:</td>
                                    <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorShipment/ActualShipDate" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/AdditionalInformation">
                                    <xsl:if test="(string-length(Name) &gt; 0) and (string-length(Value) &gt; 0)">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Name" />:</td>
                                            <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">other Order Number:</td>
                                    <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/OrderNumber" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem" />
                            <br />
                            <table style="width:100%;background-color:#dfedf3;" cellspacing="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;">Customer Service</td>
                                    <td style="width:65%">
                                        <hr style="width:100%;border:1px solid #5165a3;" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12pt;">           Please return cores within <xsl:value-of select="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem/VendorOrderItem/VendorOrder/Order/OrderChannel/ClientProgram/DaysAllowedForCoreReturn" /> days of part ship date to ensure that claim payments are not affected.<br /><br />                    If you have any questions on your core return please email us at <a href="mailto:othershared@company.com">otherShared@company.com</a>.<br /><br />                    Please don't reply to this email.  Mail sent to this address can't be answered.<br /><br /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12pt;">Please click <a href="{/CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturnLabel}" target="_blank">here</a> to view the core return label.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CoreReturnEmail/CoreReturn/VendorShipItem">
        <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; background-color : #34498c; color : white; font-size : 10pt; font-weight : bold;">
                <td style="padding:5px;">Brand</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;">Part No.</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">Description</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">Status</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">Qty.</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;">Core Charge</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-left : 2px solid #dfedf3; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3; padding : 5px;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/otherSKU/Item/Brand/PreferredName" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/otherSKU/Item/DisplayNumber" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="string(VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/otherSKU/Item/Description)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/otherSKU/Item/Description" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/OrderItemState/Name" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;text-align:right;padding:5px;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Quantity" />
                </td>
                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-right : 2px solid #dfedf3; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3; padding : 5px;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;text-align:right;" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(VendorOrderItem/OrderItem/CoreCharge, '$###,##0.00')" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which transforms to:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Core Has Been Received</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;">
      <table width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://content.gif" border="0">
              <br>
                <br>
                  <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:21pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;">Core Return:</span>
                  <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;"> Order #</span>
                  <span style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #f43400;">12345678</span>
                  <br>
                    <br>
                      <span style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14pt;">Hello        CHICAGO,</span>
                      <br>
                        <br>
                          <span style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14pt;">         This email communication is to provide the information necessary to make your core return fast and easy.         <br>
                              <br>                To complete your core return, please email <a href="mailto:othershared@company.com">otherShared@company.com</a>.              </span>
                              <br>
                                <br>
                                  <br>
                                    <table style="background-color:#dfedf3;" cellpadding="5">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">Core For:</td>
                                        <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;"/>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">Part Ship Date:</td>
                                        <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">5/31/2016</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;">other Order Number:</td>
                                        <td style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:9pt;">12345678</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <br>
                                      <br>
                                        <br>
                                          <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; background-color : #34498c; color : white; font-size : 10pt; font-weight : bold;">
                                              <td style="padding:5px;">Brand</td>
                                              <td style="padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;">Part No.</td>
                                              <td style="padding:5px;">Description</td>
                                              <td style="padding:5px;">Status</td>
                                              <td style="padding:5px;">Qty.</td>
                                              <td style="padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;">Core Charge</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-left : 2px solid #dfedf3; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3; padding : 5px;" valign="top"/>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top"/>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top"/>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;padding:5px;" valign="top">Sourced</td>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3;text-align:right;padding:5px;" valign="top">1</td>
                                              <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; border-right : 2px solid #dfedf3; border-bottom : 2px solid #dfedf3; padding : 5px;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;text-align:right;" valign="top">$40.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table>
                                          <br>
                                            <table style="width:100%;background-color:#dfedf3;" cellspacing="5">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="font-family : Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:17pt; font-weight : bold; color : #1f415c;">Customer Service</td>
                                                <td style="width:65%">
                                                  <hr style="width:100%;border:1px solid #5165a3;">
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td colspan="2" style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12pt;">           Please return cores within  days of part ship date to ensure that claim payments are not affected.<br>
                                                      <br>                    If you have any questions on your core return please email us at <a href="mailto:othershared@company.com">otherShared@company.com</a>.<br>
                                                          <br>                    Please don't reply to this email.  Mail sent to this address can't be answered.<br>
                                                              <br>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td colspan="2" style="font-family : Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12pt;">Please click <a href="https://www.example.com/SomePage.pdf?token=eaf5383bddb9382f5&amp;createdby=f01ddedb0aedd87fe44b9b9b741" target="_blank">here</a> to view the core return label.</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                          <br>
                                                            <br>
                                                              <br>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                        </body>
                                                      </html>
```

As you can see, this works perfectly. The CoreReturnLabel URL shows up in online XSL Transformations as well as NotePad++'s XSL Transformation. But, the moment it passes through the initial code:

```
 XslTransform vXslTransform = new XslTransform();
XmlReader vReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(this.Xslt));
vXslTransform.Load(vReader,null as XmlResolver, null as System.Security.Policy.Evidence);

StringWriter vStringWriter = new StringWriter();
vXslTransform.Transform(this.XmlDocument, null, vStringWriter, null);
```

...the URL is empty.

Why?

Comment: Breakpoint, debugger.

Comment: I did. That's how I know what is happening. Though, the actual XslTransform.Transform process is a black box.

Comment: And `CoreReturnLabel` appears in the debugger variable view? And is capitalized the same?

Comment: Difficult to follow when the problem appears to be a one-liner but the input and XSLT code you provide are so much longer than necessary.  If you don't want to bother to cut it down to essentials for Stack Overflow readers, then cut it down for yourself:  it helps make problems easier to see.  Are you certain that the input you are running on has the new element?

Comment: I am certain, yes. I traced the code in order to confirm.

Comment: Tested, works fine.

Comment: I know. See answer below. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. I hadn't deployed the newest application that ran the Transform to the server. When I did, this worked just fine.

Thus, the original question is actually the correct answer.